# Replace all matches except the first one

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a malformed URL like this:  http://www.abc.com/?abc&?as&?blah

Now, I want to match (and eliminate) all `?` in the URL except the first one, to make the URL clean. Is it possible using regular expressions in JavaScript? I tried positive look behind and other methods, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the best, but a possible solution: Cut the string in two at the first question mark, remove all the question marks in the second string using regex, glue them back together.

Answer (score 2):

```
var url = 'http://www.abc.com/?abc&?as&?blah';
var pos = url.search(/\?/) + 1;
var validUrl = url.substr( 0, pos )
             + url.slice( pos ).replace(/\?/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var str = "http://www.abc.com/?abc&?as&?blah";
str = str.replace(/(http:\/\/[^\/]+\/\?[^\?]+)\?([^\?]+)\?([^\?]+)/,"$1$2$3");
```

Tested it in the [javascript regular expression tester](http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm).